# How to get data from child via callBack and to add new argument to it in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am having a parent component from where i pass callBack to a child component to update value on change(dataToAdd is the data coming from the child component). But i need to be able to add one more argument that is only for  the parent. if I add collectionName to handleAdd I don't get the data from the child anymore.
how can i keep the data from the child component and have collectionName argument as well?

Here is the parent code:

```
const ParentComponent = ()=> {

const handleAdd = (dataToAdd, collectionName) => { 
 if (collectionName === 'second-jobs') {
        localSecondJobsOptions.push({
          _id: Math.random().toString(),
          name: dataToAdd.value,
          userAdded: true,
          selected: true,
        });
    } else if (collectionName === 'courses') {
      localCoursesOptions.push({
        _id: Math.random().toString(),
        name: dataToAdd.value,
        userAdded: true,
        selected: true,
      });
    }
}

   <CheckboxModal
   onAdd={() => handleAdd('second-job')}/>
}
Here is the child component:
const ChildComponent = ({onAdd}) => {
 
 const [addValue, setAddValue] = useState('');

 const localOnAdd = () => {
    onAdd({ value: addValue });
    setAddValue('');
  }
<Container>
      <Row className="ml-1 mr-4">
        <Col md="8">
          <Input
            onChange={changeAddValue}
            value={addValue}
            placeholder={addFieldPlaceholder}
          />
        </Col>
        <Col sm="12" md="4">
          <Button
            label="Add"
            variant="Button"
            onClick={localOnAdd}
          />
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row className="ml-1 mr-4">
        <Col md="8"></Col>
        <Col sm="6" md="4">
          <div className="btn-wrapper">
            <Button
              label="Opslaan"
              variant="Button-outline"
              onClick={localOnSave}
            />
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in parent component use a function that returns a function:

```
const ParentComponent = ()=> {

const handleAdd = (collectionName) => (dataToAdd) => { 
 if (collectionName === 'second-jobs') {
        localSecondJobsOptions.push({
          _id: Math.random().toString(),
          name: dataToAdd.value,
          userAdded: true,
          selected: true,
        });
    } else if (collectionName === 'courses') {
      localCoursesOptions.push({
        _id: Math.random().toString(),
        name: dataToAdd.value,
        userAdded: true,
        selected: true,
      });
    }
}

   <CheckboxModal
   onAdd={handleAdd('second-jobs')}/>
}
```

so now `handleAdd('second-jobs')` is a function that accept `dataToAdd` as parameter and in this case the `collectionName` is `second-jobs`